# VBA CODE- How to split WBS numbering into individual columns

Tags: excel, vba

struggling to separate a normal column of WBS numbering into individual columns using vba code

I'm starting off with A but want to have addition 4 columns

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |  |  |  |
| 1.1 |  | 1.1 |  |  |
| 1.2 |  | 1.2 |  |  |
| 2 | 2 |  |  |  |
| 2.1 |  | 2.1 |  |  |
| 2.1.1 |  |  | 2.1.1 |  |
| 2.1.1.1 |  |  |  | 2.1.1.1 |

Comment: Please, edit your question and show us the code you tried.

Comment: If the delimiter is the same you can use textocol: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.texttocolumns

Comment: @ceci: I am afraid, not. `TextToColumn` will split it on all the necessary/resulted columns. He looks to need calculating only the column where **the whole string** to be copied...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the next code, please:

```
Sub SplitOnColumns()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, rng As Range, arr, cel As Range
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet     'use here the sheet you need
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 
  Set rng = sh.Range("A1:A" & lastR) 'set the range to be processed
  For Each cel In rng.cells 'iterate between the range cells
        arr = Split(cel.Value, ".") 'split the cell value by "."
        'determine the necessary column (arr is 1D array)
        cel.Offset(0, UBound(arr) + 1).Value = cel.Value  
  Next
End Sub
```

The code assumes that the format of A:A column is Text

The code will run faster adding some optimization lines (`Application.ScreenUpdating = False`, `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`, `Application.EnableEvents = False`) at the beginning and made them `True`, `xlCalculationAutomatic`, `True` at the end.

Comment: @Mister Bonk Glad I could help! But we gere, when somebody answer our question, tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar  issue will know tat the code works and you prefer it, in case of more answers. If course, you should mark the answer you understand/like better, not necessary to be mine...

Answer (score 1):

or to avoid interacting with the sheet in your loop:

```
    Option Explicit
    Sub move()
        Dim arr, arr2, lastR As Long, j As Long, nrCol
        With Sheet1
            lastR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            arr = .Range("A1:A" & lastR) 'set the range to be processed
            ReDim arr2(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To 10) 'add more colls than the max len
            For j = 1 To UBound(arr)
                nrCol = split(arr(j, 1), ".")
                arr2(j, 1 + UBound(nrCol)) = arr(j, 1)
            Next j
            .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(UBound(arr2), UBound(arr2, 2))).Value2 = arr2
        End With
    End Sub
```